# Files Path on Classic Asp

Tags: asp-classic

I'm new at ASP, and I'm trying to code with a simple tree to organize my code. It is as follows:

```
-act
   connect.asp
   login.asp
-db
   database.sql
-img
   images.files
-style
   styles.css
-view
index.asp
```

For now, on training's sake, my index.asp is a login page, that calls login.asp to actually login the user. Then, that login.asp redirects him back to Index.asp. I am calling the `login.asp` just fine from my `index.asp`, because I use HTML to reference it:

```
<form action="act/login.asp" method="post">
```

But I can't call `index.asp` from my `login.asp`. I have tried

```
response.redirect(Server.MapPath("../index.asp"))
```

But as I read about MapPath, it does not accept `../` and when I just `Server.MapPath("/")` it references the current folder.

How can I navigate through my folders using ASP? I have nothing accept MapPath and it does't work with parent folders.

Comment: `.MapPath` returns a local physical path but `.Redirect` wants a URL to send back to the browser - try `response.redirect("/index.asp")`

Comment: Yes! And no "/" necessary before the "index.asp".

Comment: @ScotterMonkey actually the slash is necessary otherwise the path will be interpreted as relative to the current directory, the slash tells it to get `index.asp` from the root of the website *(assuming `index.asp` is in the root and that is what the OP wants ofc)*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you use `MapPath` it returns a local physical path, and `redirect("url")` wants a URL to redirect you to. Now, `../` does not work in ASP. So, what you can do is:

```
responde.redirect("/parentdirectory/index.asp")
```

Note that If you use the same code only with `"/index.asp"` it won't work, since `"/"` brings you to the root of the project.

Comment: ../ does work in ASP. For example: response.redirect("../index.asp") would take you "up" one folder level to a file called index.asp at that level. So if both your login and your index are in the same folder, response.redirect("index.asp") is sufficient. It just needs to happen before headers are written. Like <% response.redirect("index.asp") %> before headers.

Comment: @ScotterMonkey only if [Parent Paths is enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-parent-paths-are-disabled-by-default).